# Sites to learn the middlegame from

Tags: middlegame, websites

I have been going through some websites for practising my middle game so that I can get an advantage right away.

What are some good sites for practising the middlegame?

Comment: This is too general a question to receive any meaningful answer, what aspects of the middlegame play are you exactly interested in? If you're serious about improving, try to learn about middlegame strategy primarily from books and not *sites.* And there are plenty of excellently written ones to get started, for instance  have a look at the suggestions [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/13447/3594).

Comment: Did someone say "books"?

Comment: @Phonon I have been through multiple books, but all I want some websites so that I can access them from anywhere.

Comment: No @David You heard it wrong. I said Websites for improving middle game tactics.

Comment: @VijayRajpurohit This is the first time you mention tactics. For that, check http;//chesstempo.com

Comment: Thanks @David, I found some really useful pieces of stuff out there.